# Import csv data to SSMS

Tags: sql-server, dataframe, csv, ssms

I was trying to import a CSV file to SSMS but I always got this error and the data format is correct

> Error inserting data into table. (Microsoft. SqlServer.Import.Wizard) Input string was not in a correct format. (mscorlib)

Here is my data

[image]

And here is the error

[image]

How can I fix it and thank you

Comment: It is likely (as the error indicates) that you have malformed data in your csv file. But it is not possible to say for sure as you have not posted the data you are trying to import and so we can't see it.

Comment: This looks [familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77157580/2029983).

Comment: if you want to save yourself a lot of trouble, import stuff as text and then do the casting yourself later

Comment: Aside... _[Floating point data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql) is approximate; therefore, not all values in the data type range can be represented exactly._ In other words you probably don't want to use it to store currency or anything that requires a modicum of accuracy. If `select case when cast(0.1 as float) + cast(0.2 as float) = cast(0.3 as float) then 1 else 0 end` doesn't scare you off of `float` then nothing will, I guess.